# Link to Smart Capture Form

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder

I have a landing page which has a link leading to the Smart Capture form.The form has just 3 fields - FirstName, LastName, Email and City.

This is how my Jouney Builder interaction goes. Initially users signs up on the landing page and data goes to a DE. After this, I need to check if the LastName is empty or not. If yes, I need to send the same link again to the customer to fill in his LastName. I have been able to achieve till here.

What I would like to do now is to pre--fill his first and email address fields. He should just be able to fill in the lastname.
How can I achieve this?

How can we pre-populate the fields of SmartCapture form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When linking to the landing page from the email, use the syntax

```
<A title="Go here" href="%%microsite_base_url[default]741416[/default]%%">Go here</A>
```

That will create a link that is contextual to that subscriber, then on the landing page simple substitution can be used: %%LastName%%

Source: https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/microsites/landing_pages/

Comment: Thanks Mac! %%LastName%% is the Subscribers attribute which we can refer on the landing page. I have been able to do that successfully.   
How can I use the Data Extension fields? So from landing Page, I have got these 3 fields into my data extension. Now I need to check if any of these fields is empty, I have to send another email to the same subscriber. But this time, I need to pre-populate the ones which were shared earlier

Comment: To access a data extension, AMPScript would need to be used.  The Lookup() or LookupRow() function could be used to determine if the rows exist then use UpdateData() to update the records with the appropriate fields. https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/

Comment: Hi Mac, I need a little more help here please. I am creating a landing page with a Smart Capture form on it. I tried to use the lookup function as below  

`Var @DEColumn1, @lookupValue`
`set @lookupValue = "maneesh_gupta@network.lilly.com"`
`set @DEColumn1 = Lookup("Man-EmailRegister", "FirstName", "SubscriberKey", @lookupValue)`  

Did this in the Processing tab of the SmartCapture form. And then used the value of @DEColumn1 in the FirstName field like below  

`<input type="text" maxlength="50" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="%%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%" size="75" />`

But no value shows up.

Comment: The part where you set variables and call Lookup() needs to be in the presentation portion of the Smart Capture form, not the processing.  The processing tab represents what happens when the form is submitted, not what happens when the form is loaded to display.

Comment: Thanks very much Mac! It worked. My head is much clear now. I got another question though - For any email that is sent out, Is there some built-in parameter/variable which can give me the SubscriberKey or EmailAddress of that subscriber?

Comment: The default parameters are: EmailAddr for email address and _SubscriberKey for SubscriberKey.  Full list: http://help.exacttarget.com/en-GB/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/